# Jquery - select all <a>s but those have parents .x

Tags: jquery

I want to select all `<a>`s but those have parents `.x`

I've tried

```
$(":not(.x)").find("a")
```

but realized you need a selector before `:not` for it to work.

How can you select those? Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select all a elements, then exclude `.x a` elements like

```
$("a").not(".x a")
```

Comment: Wow! I was only conscious about the children and methods after the `$("")`, thank you! Now I've learned a new thing :D

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest:

```
$('a').filter(function(){
    return $(this).closest('.x').length === 0;
});
```

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jQuery.com/closest/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jQuery.com/filter/).

Comment: Your answer was also good, but I'm sorry I had to accept Arun's answer. +1

Comment: That's fine, the answer you choose is entirely your choice. I'm glad to have helped, however.

Answer (score 0):

You do something like this:

```
$('a').each(function(){

    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('x')){
        // Do Something

    }
});
```

Comment: It will create lag and I don't really want a loop in my single line.